# AspNet Mvc select ConnectionString automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I have been working on a project for sometime now which has production version running on a shared hosting environment and one on my development machine.
The issue here is that each time I want to run the application on my development machine, I will have to modify Connection String settings to point at the localDb on development machine and vice versa when I want to publish.
This became so inconvenient for me until I came up with this solutions which is working perfectly at least.
My question is this, Is this my solution professional and reliable in Aspnet environment ? Or is there a best and proven way of achieving this solution better? thank you. please see code for details.

```
//Created a static method in Global.asax.cs     

/// <summary>
   /// Returns Connection settings based on the machine. i.e, automatically select connection strings if it's development or live server
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="ArrayIndex"></param>
   /// <returns> string BaseConn = (connectionstring name) </returns>

public  static string

     Settings( int ArrayIndex)
    {


        string[] BaseConn ={ HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal ? System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[4].Name :
         System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].Name,

//Identity database connections

         HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal ? System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[5].Name :
         System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[2].Name,

//store database connection

         HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal ? System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[6].Name :
         System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[3].Name,
                              };
        return BaseConn[ArrayIndex];
    }
```

Then I called the method in DbContext class a follow

```
public class MyAppDb :DbContext

{


    public MyAppDb()
        : base(MvcApplication.Settings(0))
    { }

// Some entity tables here
}
```

I Did the same for the  store DbContext and Identity DbContext.
Everything seems working great both on local and live machine. though I have not been able to update the databases with this solution using codefirst migration. Not an Issue at least for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use  Web.Release.Config.

In Web.config you will specify your own (local) connection string and on release you will use something like this (change the config according to your own sql connection).

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SalvaVidas;Server=ServerName;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
         xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Make sure that the name property match in both. In this example it is : name="MyContext"

NOTE: Please make sure that when you are publishing, it is going as RELEASE mode.

Comment: Thank you so much Codebased for your time. This seems like standard way of doing it. I should use this instead of my own solution though working without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You better use **Web.Config Transformations** instead.

The idea is that upon deployment, you choose the target environment and the configuration file will be transformed automatically according to the changes described in `Web.{CONFIGURATION_NAME}.config` file.

For example, to change the Connection-String for the `Release` configuration you're gonna need this in your `Web.Release.config` file:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" 
      connectionString="{SQL_SERVER_CONNECTION_STRING_FOR_RELEASE}" 
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

See [Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations)

Comment: Thanks man for your time. Thanks for the link too. it gave me more insight on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So when someone forgets (and someone will) to set "release" or "debug" mode your system will be hitting either development data or production data by mistake, this seems like a recipe for disaster....this just does not seem fail proof to me. There has to be a way of coding this in to the application. For example you can code so that your application determines what server it is running on, if it's the production server then use the production connection string....if it's the test server then use the test connection string, else use the development connection string.